# Android Sugar db

Tags: android, database, sugarorm

images of what I've done so far
  [This is working insert code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjsEr.png)
and this is
  [cont](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGxrN.png)

This is working view code

```
ArrayAdapter<Book> adapter;
ListView mListview;
mListview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listBooks);
List<Book> list = Book.listAll(Book.class);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Book>(ViewAllBooks.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
mListview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is what I'm having trouble with

This doesn't work I'm trying to update the book by title

```
book.title = "updated title here";
book.edition = "3rd edition";
book.save();
```

*I can't seem to get an individual item deleted like what the sugar db
 website says*

```
Book book = Book.findById(Book.class, 1);
book.delete();
```

Comment: What is your question? Is the problem with deleting or updating?

Answer (score 0):

you can update the saved object like this

```
Book book = (Book.find(Book.class, "id = ?", 1)).get(0);
book.setTitle("updated title here");
book.setEdition("3rd edition");
book.save();
```

Comment: Ill try that but what about deleting? thanks for the reply